# Show only year in angular material datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I was looking at the [Angular Material documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker) for date picker. I was wondering if there is any way to show only the years in the date picker? Appreciate it if someone could help me out with it.

Answer (score 1):

With md-datepicker Selecting only year is **`not`** possible, month year format is possible using `md-mode="month"`.

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/kbZ7EI?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

there is a little feint you set the datepicker opened to false , after year selected

```js
    chosenYearHandler(normalizedYear: Moment,datepicker: MatDatepicker<Moment>) {
        // your code
        datepicker.opened = false
    }
```